# HDMI to CSI Converter for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, converter, video, hdmi, csi

I am creating a HDMI to CSI converter, but i dont know if the wiring is correct and if i need to add any passive component. can you guys help me out?[image]

[EasyEDA Project](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=%7Cbb836068811a4d81b24e448d51960650)

Comment: I can tell you right now you'll definitely need to add some passives.

Comment: where? and the wiring is correct?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about the wiring for this. Never worked with either of these protocols before.

Comment: neither i, that's the problem xD

Comment: Are you sure you want to re-invent a device which can already be purchased for $70 in single quantities?

Comment: @Justme is talking about this product: https://auvidea.eu/b101-hdmi-to-csi-2-bridge-15-pin-fpc/. If this is more of a learning project rather than solving the HDMI-in problem on RPi, the image of the PCB gives you a good idea on the amount of additional components required. Here's a link to a download of the datasheet of the Toshiba IC: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/product/assp/interface-bridge/detail.TC358743XBG.html. It should at least get you started on getting the right passives in place.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring is not complete in any way and even now connecting a HDMI source will fry the chip as 5V line is connected to 2.5V supply. Multiple supply and ground pins are unconnected. Not only passives such as bypass capacitors and reference voltage set resistor are needed, but a lot of other active components as well, such as reference clock source like a crystal oscillator module and voltage regulators to generate all the required power supplies. I hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't saw the 2.5 error, just a mistake.